# printf span long command over multiple lines

Tags: html, bash, printf, lines

Is it possible within bash script, to have long `printf` command spanned over multiple lines?

My command is something like this, and I would like it to be more readable.
Braces are there because it's acutally part of `awk` block.

```
sqlite3 -noheader -column database.db "select * from tbl_a limit $limit" | \
        awk 'BEGIN { FS = "|"; }
                { printf "\t\t<tr>\n\t\t\t<td class=\"d\">%s</td>\n\t\t\t<td class=\"m\">%s</td>\n\t\t</tr>\n", $1, $2 }' | vim -
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In `awk`, you can use line-continuation characters to split the string across multiple lines.

```
sqlite3 -noheader -column database.db "select * from tbl_a limit $limit" |
    awk 'BEGIN { FS = "|"; }
         { printf "\t\t<tr>\n\
\t\t\t<td class=\"d\">%s</td>\n\
\t\t\t<td class=\"m\">%s</td>\n\
\t\t</tr>\n", $1, $2 }' | vim -
```

Or, instead of using `awk`, you can process the output of sqlite line-by-line in `bash`:

```
sqlite3 -noheader -column database.db "select * from t/l_a limit $limit" |
  while IFS='|' read col1 col2; do
      printf '\t\t<tr>
\t\t\t<td class="d">%s</td>
\t\t\t<td class="m">%s</td>
\t\t</tr>\n' "$col1" "$col2"
  done | vim -
```

Comment: I would rather stick with your previous suggestion, on having `\n` emebedded, as it's much cleaner.

Comment: Unfortunately, you can't have embedded newlines in `awk`.

Comment: Second solution without `awk` seems even better. I will go with that. Thank You!

Comment: Can I have that `|` symbol, without `\\` after it?

Comment: Yes; since a command cannot end with an unquoted pipe, `bash` knows to wait for more input to complete the command.